# Print expressions using local variables in Module without Dollar sign: is that possible

Tags: scoping, printing

In a Module, I want to print the result of some data fit. I use something like this:

```
PlotDD[r_, n_, R_] :=
 Module[{d, fit, ft, pl, x}
       ,ft = Table[{d, PythAbst[5, r, n, d, R]}, {d, 0., 10, .1}];
        d =.;
        fit = ToString[Fit[ft, {1, d, d^2}, d]];
        Print["ft[d]=", fit];
        ...
       ];
```

The output of the print statement is:

```
ft[d]=                                                   2
0.000402667 + 0.11131 d$28040 + 0.000883443 d$28040
```

where the 2 in the first line is the exponent of d$28040.

I know, appending  a Dollar sign plus some unique number is how local variables of Module are made. But I want it printed without this $-number, I would like it as

```
ft[d]=0.000402667 + 0.11131 d$ + 0.000883443 d^2
```

I avoid the exponent in an extra line applying InputForm first. I tried to enclose things in `N[#,6]` to limit digits to something physically meaningful but the latter does not work for me. **Any idea about this?**

Comment: You could perhaps use `Block` instead of `Module`. This will clear the values of the variables that you specify (and restore the old values when done), but not create new unique identifiers for them. Also, using `LinearModelFit` or `NonlinearModelFit` instead of `Fit` gives you better-formatted output directly.

Comment: You could add `d /: MakeBoxes[d, StandardForm] = "d"` at the top of your Module.

Comment: Yes, MarcoB, after I changed Module to Block it changed the appearance of Print as desired. However with block, utmost care has to be applied if any global symbol is used in it! If any of the local variables from Block’s first parameter vars also appears in the current value of a global variable accessed inside Block, it immediately assumes the value of Block’s own local variables substituted into the global symbol’s expression: That's like a chameleon! They call this dynamic scoping (execution history scoping) rather than lexical scoping to which I am more used to.

Comment: No, Carl Woll, I made it `PlotDD[r_, n_, R_] := Module[{d, fit, ft, pl, x}, d /: MakeBoxes[d, StandardForm] = "d";  ft = Table[{d, PythAbst[17, r, n, d, R]}, {d, 0., 10, 0.1}];  fit = ToString[InputForm[N[Fit[ft, {1, d, d^2}, d], 6]]];  Print["ft[d]=", fit]; ];` but I still got print results with `d$8586` and with `d$8586^2`. - Any idea about how to coerce the numbers to 6 relevant digits?

Answer (score 4):

The basic issue is the use of [`ToString`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ToString.html) and [`InputForm`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/InputForm.html). There is no need for them, since [`Print`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Print.html) works with expressions as well as strings. Here is a function that takes some data, and prints the quadratic fit, using my earlier suggestion in the comments:

```
PlotDD[data_] := Module[{d, fit},
    d /: MakeBoxes[d, StandardForm] = "d";
    fit = Fit[data, {1, d, d^2}, d];
    Print["ft[d]=", fit]
]
```

An example from the documentation of [`Fit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Fit.html)

```
PlotDD[{{0,1},{1,0},{3,2},{5,4}}]
```

> ft[d]=0.678392 -0.266332 d+0.190955 d^2

Comment: What if we do not tag? `MakeBoxes[d, StandardForm] = "d";`

Answer (score 2):

I use the following function

```
str[expr_]:=Module[{},StringReplace[ToString[expr,
   FormatType->TraditionalForm],c:LetterCharacter~~"$"~~DigitCharacter..:>c]];
```

To use, just wrap the content you want the `$` removed from by this function. Example usage using Carl example below.

```
PlotDD[data_]:=Module[{d,fit},
  fit=Fit[data,{1,d,d^2},d];
  Print["ft[d]=",str@fit]]
PlotDD[{{0,1},{1,0},{3,2},{5,4}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

I did not write the above function. It was written by answer to my question on this many years ago by **Hannes Kessler** in this post at now closed group [comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/_IKdV2GJzSc) and I've used it since and it works well.

Comment: Answer by Nasser did it for me. Although it works better if you change LetterCharacter for WordCharacter... That's to include variables which end in DigitCharacter as well... for example
A1$91823 will be ignored if you use LetterCharacter